# Why isn't this media query working?

Tags: css, image, media-queries

I am trying to trigger a smaller image for all my pages on the website when viewed on a smaller screen/device. I've written this for a certain page(s) and it isn't working.  It either applies to all pages, unintentionally or not at all.

```
@media screen and (min-width : 240px) and (max-width : 667px) {
    .page-id-59, img {
        height: 80%;
        width: 80%;
    }
}
```

Also what's the best way to do this?  Should it load a small size of the image or download a large size and scale it to the screen?  I am not sure what the best thing is.

The page-id in the query is to identify the specific page but it isn't doing that.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You have a stray comma

Answer (score 1):

`.page-id-59, img {`

you are saying "all items with class 'page-id-59' OR all items with tag `IMG` "

you should remove that comma

Answer (score 0):

This selector

```
.page-id-59, img {...
```

adresses *all* elements with class `page-id-59` AND all `img` elements on the website.

If you want to address only `img` elements on the page with class `page-id-59`, write it without a comma:

```
.page-id-59 img {...
```

Comment: How about a specific photo on a different page?  I can't use the .page-id-000 img { to address the elements.  suggestions?

Comment: To address a specific photo you can either simply apply an ID to the `img`  tag (in HTML) and set up a CSS rule for that, or use the `nth-of-type` selector in combination with the page class, like `.page-id-47 img:nth-of-type(3) {...}`, which will address the third image on page 47.